# How to implement mod_rewrite after PHP redirection?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a lot of old urls I need to redirect to certain categories.

- **www.example.com/some-requested-product** -> **www.example.com/index.php?categories=some-requested-product**
- **www.example.com/some-requested-article** -> **www.example.com/index.php?articles=some-requested-article**
- **www.example.com/some-requested-user** -> **www.example.com/index.php?users=some-requested-user**

And so on - I hope you get the point. (Actually there's no hint in the URL about the content type.)

I've created a redirection, now I can reach the content I need:

- **RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /index.php%{REQUEST_URI}**

In the PHP I can query now the urls to see what type of content it is:

- **if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/some-requested-content") { Redirect($BaseURL."/index.php?category_type=some-requested-content", false); }**

Redirection is made, content is fetched. (I know it's not safe etc. just for testing.)

***My main problem is now, how can I mask the URL after these events?***

I would like to see the same URL originally requested ( www.example.com/some-requested-content ) in the address bar of the browser, not the one it is redirected to.

Is it possible?
Or can you think about another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for query string append ([QSA](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA))

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some-requested-article$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?articles=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some-requested-product
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?categories=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and so on, you'd make the regex cover each case of query string, like category, articles, users, and so on.

The L means last to process in the rewrite rules, that's very important to use.

This preserves the visible URI, but internally passes the page processing the request the desired query string data.

So you aren't really 'masking' the url, the url is basically simply filling in the desired query string data, which is then sent to the file processing the request. This is a common method, it's how a lot of blogging and cms platforms handle search engine friendly urls, for example.

Note however that because you didn't provide a more accurate example of your real urls in each case, the solution I am posting would require regex that handles the variable values. If there is no actual pattern difference between the types, then you can't use this method, you'd have to go down the list of exact values/urls per query string type and list them as possible matches using the [OR] option in the RewriteCond tests. That works as long as there aren't too many pages involved.

Like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/beans-are-fun$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/rice-is-fun$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/fun-with-rice-and-beans$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?articles=$1 [L,QSA]
```